# Use foreach in drupal array?

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, foreach

I want to create a statistics page in a `Drupal 7` module. But for that I actually need to do a `foreach` inside an `array`.. I think this is not possible but I'm not 100% sure about this.

this is my code at the moment (doesn't work, concatenated wrong etc..)

Does anyone know if this is possible and can give a little example how to do it

My code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$query = db_query('SELECT * FROM push_notifications_messages WHERE app_id = :app_id', array(':app_id' => $id));
$qCount = db_query('SELECT * FROM push_notifications_messages WHERE app_id = :app_id', array(':app_id' => $id))->rowCount();

$form['table'] = array(
'#theme' => 'table',
'#header' => array(t('Message'), t('Device'), t('Date')),
'#rows' => array(
    foreach($query as $result) {
      for($i = 1; $i <= $qCount; $i++) {
        echo "'r" . $i . "'" . => array(
            "'c1'" . => array(
                '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#title' => t('@message', array('@message' => $result['msg_message']))
              ),
            "'c2'" . => array(
                '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#title' => t('@device', array('@device' => $result['msg_device']))
              ),
          ),
      }
    }
  ),
);
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Just extract your foreach loop out of the array definition and then assign the values after it like this:

```
<?php

    $form['table'] = array(
        '#theme' => 'table',
        '#header' => array(t('Message'), t('Device'), t('Date')),
        '#rows' => array(),
    );



    foreach($query as $result) {
      for($i = 1; $i <= $qCount; $i++) {
        $form['table']["#rows"]["'r$i'"] = array(
            "'c1'" => array(
                '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#title' => t('@message', array('@message' => $result['msg_message']))
              ),
            "'c2'" => array(
                '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#title' => t('@device', array('@device' => $result['msg_device']))
              ),
          );
      }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works so far only it doesn't display the "title" in the table. I also tried adding some hardcored string in it, and tried #markup instead of #title but it shows empty results.

Comment: @user3428971 What do you mean with *doesn't display* you just assign a new element to an array. So you won't see anything. Maybe do: `print_r($form);` to see the structure of your array.

Comment: I mean on the page where the form table is displayed it now looks like this:  http://i57.tinypic.com/dp8mkx.jpg. While it should display the #title => t('text here') right?

Comment: @user3428971 I don't see anything wrong in the code. As I said I can only say to do: `print_r($form);` and look at the structure if it is correct for your needs

Comment: I see.. I also did dsm($form) now and it does display the results. Also when I use inspect elements I see them. But it doesn't place them between the <td></td> tags. but inside the first <td>: <td #type="textfield" #value="hoi" #data="hoi"></td>

Comment: @user3428971 I'm out of ideas here. Don't know why your code fails to display the results

Answer (score 0):

You should not use echo,foreach kind of PHP codes inside a drupal form builder code. Without giving any comment I would like to share [this](http://e9p.net/theming-drupal-7-form-elements-table) with you. Hope it will help you better than me.